# what is a CAR (Connector Archive) in Geronimo or Tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat, geronimo

In some EAR file based deployments, I saw "car" file as type. 
How does it work? How is different from a JAR or WAR file?

Answer (score 1):

A "CAR" is a "Configuration ARchive"; a WAR is a "Web Application aRchive", and an EAR is an "Enterprise Application aRchive" (which can consist of multiple WAR's).

Here's a link that discusses how to use CAR's to backup WebSphere configurations; the concept is similar for Geronimo:

- [IBM WebSphere Configuration Archives](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.was_v6/was/6.0/SystemManagement/WASv6_SM_Configuration_Archives/player.html)

Comment: Thank you for the information. It is very hard to find any info on CAR. The video doesn't provide the full details of the CAR format. But, any information is great.